# $\sigma$-algebra and algebra questions

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

A probability measure $\mu$ can only be defined for events (subsets) of $\Omega$ that are found in any $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$.

---

I read that a $\sigma$-algebra is a special kind of algebra.

**Algebra**: collection of subsets closed under **finite** unions and intersections.

**Sigma algebra**: collection of subsets closed under **countable** unions and intersections.

(where "closed under" basically means that if operator * is applied to subsets of a set then the result is still in the set)

But, I also read that **countable** can be thought of as being between finite and infinite (i.e. countable > finite) and therefore countable additivity includes finite additivity.

So, if countable > finite then **countable unions** should include more subsets of a set than **finite union**. Therefore, (it seems to me) that a $\sigma$-algebra (on a set) is a more comprehensive concept than algebra (on a set) and I am left confused by the statement that: "a $\sigma$-algebra is a special kind of algebra. Since it should be the other way around i.e. that an algebra is a special kind of $\sigma$-algebra. Any ideas?

Comment: You forgot complementation.

Comment: However, you can say that $A_0\cup A_1=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N} A_n$, with $A_n=A_1$ for all $n\ge 1$, if by countable unions you mean unions of sequences indexed by $\Bbb N$. Not so much for unions of subfamilies, the cardinalities of which are a bit sketchier to evaluate in a practical proof (as opposed to devising a sequence ranging over a known countable set being comparatively easy).

Answer (score 2):

Any $\sigma$-algebra is an algebra since as you point out closure under countable unions implies closure under finite unions. The converse is not true, there are algebras which are not $\sigma$-algebras. For example the collection of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ which are either finite or cofinite form an algebra which is not a $\sigma$-algebra. So the collection of $\sigma$-algebras is a subclass of the collection of algebras and a $\sigma$-algebra is a specific type of algebra.

Comment: I get the first sentence. But, I don't understand how a set could be an algebra but not a $\sigma$-algebra, since countable > finite and therefore if a set obey finite union doesn't it necessarily also obey countable unions?

Comment: Countable $\implies$ finite is what gets us that any $\sigma$-algebra is an algebra. Consider $\{2n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, this is a countable set that is not finite. In the example above $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \{2n\}$ is a countable union which is neither finite nor cofinite. But $\{2n\}$ is finite for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, so this witnesses that the collection of finite and cofinite sets is not a $\sigma$-algebra.